# Getting path to parent process from child process

Tags: c, windows

I need to retrieve the path of a parent process, by just looking at the child process.

The parent process is DEAD, meaning the parent process created the child process, and then the parent process exited.

So I am another process, who has the handle to the child process, and I need to know who created this process(the child process).

Comment: Opps should have mentioned, this is for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this article [Process termination](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/05/03/2383346.aspx)

> When your program calls ExitProcess a whole lot of machinery springs
>   into action. First, all the threads in the process (except the one
>   calling ExitProcess) are forcibly terminated. The kernel will close
>   all your open handles to kernel objects. Any memory you allocated will
>   be freed automatically when the process's address space is torn down.

Therefore can't get any information about that process once it is died.

Answer (score 1):

Once a process has exited, and all handles to it have been closed, the system forgets everything about it.  There is no way to retrieve this information in the scenario described.